# After RedirectToAction Return Back To The Calling Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two actions in different controllers, Action1 calling Action2 view.

Is there a way to come back after seconds to Action1 to continue?

Action 1:

```
//POST - CREATE
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateEditInstitutionViewModel model)
        {
               //..........SOME CODE.............
                _db.Request.Add(request);

                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("ShowMessagePage", new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "MessagePage", Action = "ShowMessagePage", myMsg = "heloo", i = true }));
                //i want to comeback here to continue
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index)); 
                

        }
```

Action2:

```
public IActionResult ShowMessagePage(string myMsg,bool isDone)
        {
            if(isDone)
                return View(new MessageViewModel { msg=myMsg}); // i want to go back to Action1
            return NotFound();
        }
```

Comment: What you want is impossible - or at least it's impossible in the way you're asking for it. `ShowMessagePage` returns a view. So, presumably, you want the user to see that view, and read the message? Therefore, you must return the view to the browser, which means the C# script must provide a response to the HTTP request, and then the script will end (because that's how web applications work). If you want, you could make the message view auto-redirect after a few seconds, by using some JavaScript.

Comment: as @ADyson pointed out, you are talking about views getting redirected, which should happen on javascript.